# Html of an div Box to a new Html site

Tags: jquery, html

i want to program an WYSIWYG Editor with Html 5 and Query. Now i have on the left side of my page, some Query elements like a Button, a TextBox....
This elements, you can drag from the left side and drop there in the centre div box.

It is possible to convert the value of the centre div box, to a new Html site?(What you see in the center div box, should be in a standalone Html site)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you be a bit clearer?

Comment: He wants a center div that he can drag and drop elements onto. Then, when you're done, whatever is left in the center div is a standalone site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!! You can take the `div.innerHTML` which alone is just HTML and this can be wrapped inside a body tag of another html page that you want to maintain on another site.

You can save this content as a `test.html` file

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="divEdit" contentEditable="true"></div>
    <button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('divEdit').innerHTML)">See HTML</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And open on a browser; type something in the div (also supports formatting, so you can bold and italicize some content) and hit the button. You will see the HTML that the div control emits.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you looking for:

```
<div class="clickable" url="http://google.com">
       Anything
    </div>

$("div.clickable").click(
function()
{
    window.location = $(this).attr("url");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the value of any element and set it as a variable and later you can use it.

```
var text = $('Your element').val();
```